# sending data to table view when tapping a button using delegate pattern

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I have a collectionView and there is a button on the each cell. When I tap the button, I'd like to display a table view cell with the data. The collection view cell had using the delegate pattern. I'd appreciate your help.

this is the collectionViewCell class:

```
protocol DataTransformationDelegate: AnyObject {

}

class SlotCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var subtitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var favoriteButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnail: UIImageView!
weak var delegate: DataTransformationDelegate?

var favorite = false {
    didSet {
        if favorite {
            favoriteButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "favoriteOn"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            favoriteButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "favoriteOff"), for: .normal)
        }
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

@IBAction func favoriteButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    favorite.toggle()
}
}
```

this is the table view controller that I wanna show the cell that I chose as favorite:

```
class FavoriteTableViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
let slotCollectionViewCell = SlotCollectionViewCell()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: String(describing: FavoriteTableViewCell.self), bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: FavoriteTableViewCell.self))

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

@IBAction func toCollectionViewTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: String(describing: ThumbnailCollectionViewController.self), bundle: nil)
    let thumbnailCollectionVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThumbnailCollectionViewController") as! ThumbnailCollectionViewController
    thumbnailCollectionVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(thumbnailCollectionVC, animated: true)
}
}

 extension FavoriteTableViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 90
 }
 }

extension FavoriteTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return MockData.mockData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: FavoriteTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! FavoriteTableViewCell

    let currentDateTime = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .long

    let mockData = MockData.mockData[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = mockData.title
    cell.subtitle.text = mockData.subtitle
    cell.date.text = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDateTime))"
    cell.thumbnail.image = UIImage(named: mockData.thumbnail)

    return cell
}
}
```

I tried to figure out how to use the delegate pattern in that case but I just can't make it so I'd appreciate your help to be able to send the data that is shown in the collection view cell to table view cell by tapping a button on collection view cell.